# LatLon package for python 3.6

Tags: python

I was searching for a package for finding latitude and longitude . I found LatLon but it is not supported in python 3 and above.
Can anybody tell me is there any other package through which I can Calculate latitude and longitude

Comment: Not calculating latitude and longitude but for find the location  through them

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. However, asking for a package or library is explicitly off-topic for this site. Instead, describe the problem and [what has been done so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) to solve it. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I think [GeoPy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy) already does that.

What are you exactly trying to do though? It'll help for better answers

---

After reading your comment, you can try [PyGeocoder](https://chrisalbon.com/python/geocoding_and_reverse_geocoding.html29) -

```
from pygeocoder import Geocoder

location = Geocoder.reverse_geocode(12.9716,77.5946)
print("City:",location.city)
print("Country:",location.country)
```

> ```
> City: Bangalore
> Country: India
> ```

Comment: Thank you. Actually i want to find the location through latitude and longitude values.

Comment: So location name from latitude and longitude values or vice-versa?

Comment: Yeah location name from latitude and longitude values.I have tried, below is the code

Comment: from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
geolocator = GoogleV3() location_list=geolocator.reverse(latitude,longitude)                        location = location_list[0]
address=location.address
print("Location :",address)

Comment: I will get the location for at most 3 runs after that it gives me an error saying 'Service timed out'

Comment: Im not sure of the timed out issue. It worked for me. Have updated the answer with PyGeocoder.